# Parasitic oscillation don't happen in an emitter follower

Tags: oscillation, emitter-follower, parasitic

This is an emitter follower from "Learning the Art of Electronics" by Hayes and Horowitz (lab 9L.2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXrHEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The autors claim that this sircuit should oscillate when probing the emitter and that they saw a sinewave of a couple of volts at about 60 MHz when they tried it).

I can't reproduce it. My power supply wires are about 60 cm long and I expected the oscillation to happen, but it didn't. The only oscillation I saw is a kind of noisy and deformed sine wave of about 10mV at about 1.5 MHz. Obviosly this is not the oscillation the authors claim should happen. Then I tried to connect an additional wire of about 2 meters long between the power supply and the collector - the same result.

My scope is Gw Instek GDS-1072A-U. The probe is GTP-070A-4 set to x1. Both power supplies are AB-3000 from Abra Electronics. The circuit is built on a breadboard.

I would appreciate any suggestions about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What probe and oscilloscope?

Comment: How did you built the circuit? Soldered directly onto wires, or on a PCB, on a vero board, or a breadboard?

Comment: 1.5 Mhz could be a local AM broadcast station (if you're in North America)...if so, then your emitter follower isn't oscillating at this frequency. When built on a printed circuit board with very short paths, this often oscillates for me... but oscillation frequency is too high to see on most oscilloscopes. Capacitors (one from base to GND, another from emitter to GND) were 10uF electrolytic type.

Comment: I think more important is V2. It has to be a hard source with low output impedance. So not some soft resistor divider.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put some details in the question initially (like my scope model etc.). Now they are there. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

I have a breadboard out right now, let me give it a try...

Let's see here.  With standard 10x passive probes, a 350MHz oscilloscope, and different voltages because it's handy (2V base, 6V collector, 220Ω emitter resistor), I find it reliably oscillates with an extra 10+ pF from C to E, or 33pF from E to B.  That's using an 18" clip lead to the collector, picking up voltage from the far end of the breadboard, so the total loop length is about 30".

You'll excuse me if I don't include a photograph of the setup; it's too messy to be illustrative.  Err, I mean, it's plenty messy to help cause oscillation, yes, let's go with that. ;)

For different bias conditions, or "lucky" faster or larger transistors, it may oscillate with just breadboard capacitance, or truly none (extra) at all.

Ah here we go, I've found a 2N4401 that oscillates on its own; higher junction capacitance is probably doing it.  Base voltage is now 2.6V; it has higher hFE as well.  It's making about 1Vpp at 44MHz, with a peaky waveform.  Hovering my hand near most any part of the circuit (including the supply wires and the probe handle) affects the waveform; there is considerable common-mode voltage induced around the loop area of the jumper wire.

Note that wires have inductance, proportional to length, and a geometry factor.  For a one-turn loop, the geometry factor is close to 0.5, and the magnetic constant is 1.257 µH/m, so this makes about 0.48 µH.  At 44MHz, that's 133 Ω reactance.  When is a wire not a wire?  Usually, when it's an inductance.

Note also that solderless breadboards have about 4pF between adjacent rows.  It doesn't take much pondering to suspect this -- they're just rows of spring contacts shoved into a plastic frame.  The plastic is fairly thin, and there's a lot of face area common between rows.  Sometimes there's a metal backing plate (which is the case for my test just now; aha, oscillation goes away if I remove its ground connection!).

Indeed, you can make "gimmick" capacitors on breadboard by wiring adjacent rows in parallel; while most of the time, this capacitance is undesirable, it can be used to ones' advantage at times.

The scope probe is some capacitance as well, though it's damped by the cable resistance and characteristic impedance.  Typically a 10x probe is around 10 or 20pF, and the resistance might vary from 100s Ω near cutoff (100s MHz), to ~MΩ at audio frequencies and DC.  The ESR and C vary with frequency because it's not simply a series circuit, it's a parallel-series circuit and different elements dominate in different frequency bands.

As for oscillation, I won't go into the analysis here, but suffice it to say, a reactance on the collector, and enough capacitance between pins, makes some manner of Colpitts oscillator.  Another perspective is that, for capacitance applied to the emitter terminal, the base has negative resistance; that's with respect to a common collector, but collector clearly isn't very "common" in this arrangement, at this frequency, so we can equally well say it's negative resistance from base to collector, and with base more "common" this time, the collector seems to have negative resistance.  Which dutifully oscillates with the attached reactance; 0.48 µH at 44 MHz implies 27 pF, which is reasonably in the ballpark for the circuit.

**Apocrypha**

This scenario, I believe, comes from (or was inspired by) postings by John Larkin on the sci.electronics.design newsgroup, where Win Hill often hangs out (or did? I haven't been there in years myself).  This was a question JL liked to use for interview purposes; as he's in the business of high speed and analog circuitry, the relative obscurity of such a question for interview purposes is arguably justified by the relative obscurity of work they do, and thus talent they seek.

In any case, the basic version was something like: +15V to collector, base to GND, resistor from emitter to -15V; label the node voltages.  And then a leading prompt for anything else, like, would it oscillate, what would you do about it, etc.

Supposedly, many interviewees didn't even label the voltages correctly -- notice two are *as given*, and the remaining one is easily solved if you've passed 2nd year EE curriculum.  Well, perhaps that was due to the general quality of candidates in their pool, but perhaps it was just a symptom of candidates under interview pressure; or Mr. Larkin just liked to rag on these exceptional cases... newsgroups are a weird environment.

---

More generally, this is a situation which shows up often enough that one should be aware of it: to be suspicious anywhere long lead lengths and large node capacitances (in particularly unlucky situations, even fairly small capacitances, as you can see!) show up around a transistor.

This isn't at all specific to BJTs, but shows up for all types:

I once built a wideband amplifier with JFET front end; input was wired through a 100Ω twisted pair, which dutifully functioned as tuned stub, causing the circuit to oscillate at some low 100s MHz; a termination network damped that out.  (The JFETs were small, ca. 5pF from drain or source to gate, but since the transmission line's unterminated Q factor was high, it would've taken very little coupling indeed to make a tuned-gate oscillator.)

Another common situation is switching MOSFETs oscillating during the transition.  Modern Si power MOSFETs exhibit significant gain up to even 400MHz; while it's not enough gain to deliver substantial power, it's still enough to oscillate at some 10s of V, and easily blow out your emissions levels for example.  The key warning sign here is a low impedance loop from gate to source, presenting some kind of resonant circuit at very high frequencies.  A typical case is a large capacitor G-S (used to slow the switching speed, in load switching / power enable sorts of applications); at RF, the large capacitor looks like a short circuit and thus the loop inductance (maybe 10s of nH!) resonates with gate capacitance.  Another case is a small G-S capacitance, such as from a protection zener -- perhaps you have a floating switch, or series stack, or a linear regulator, and you need to ensure Vgs is limited in all conditions; here, the diode's junction capacitance resonates with the loop inductance.  In both cases, a small gate resistance (can even be a ferrite bead*) kills Q factor of the loop, preventing oscillation.  This is why you almost always want a resistor directly at the gate pin of a switching MOSFET.

*I once had a switching circuit with 200V 25A transistors in a push-pull configuration, with nice wide stripline connections from the gate drivers to the inverter section (the connections were relatively long because of prototype/breadboarding reasons).  They dutifully resonated, probably the inductance of the stripline (thanks to the width, it was still quite low: only a few 10s of nH) resonating with gate capacitance.  Oscillation was a burst a handful of cycles long, at 200MHz or something like that, during the otherwise quite rapid (10s ns) transition period.  A ferrite bead threaded over the gate pin, quenched the oscillation alright, but got quite hot itself: I was switching at 1-2MHz, and the ferrite bead doesn't stop being a resistance: it's most definitely causing losses in the gate drive circuit, too!  (Which increased gate transition time, but only slightly, actually.)

The ferrite beads weren't even as effective as they could be, because they were indeed fully saturating during peak gate drive: with ~5V dropped across one for 10ns or so, rising to a peak current of 2-3A, the ferrite is driven into saturation and its impedance falls off quite sharply.  There was still some instability on the rising edge, but like merely a half-cycle attempt at oscillation, not a full breakout.  There was also a little rebound (ringing) on the flat (gate-high) portion of the waveform, though nowhere near enough to be worried about.  (The amount of overshoot is limited by saturation; the ferrite bead might be 0.5-1uH at zero bias, but little energy is stored in that inductance by the time it saturates.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this effort!! Appreciated to see! +1

Answer (score 2):

On a breadboard, there might be about 5pf capacitance between rows. Typically, you'd push the 2N3904 into three adjacent rows, resulting in:

- 5pf between base and collector
- 5pf between base and emitter

If you add the 470 ohm resistor to the next row, and GND to the row below that...
then you have 5pf across the 470 ohm resistor to GND. This GND pin is where you also tie the 10nf capacitor.
Now let's use a 10nf capacitor with fairly long leads, so that inductance of these wires becomes significant at very high frequencies. OP's schematic above shows no inductance, but its hidden in the wiring - this is a classic common-collector colpitts oscillator. In the left-most schematic below, C2 and C3 represent breadboard capacitances. L1 is the inductance of C1's long wires:
[image: schematic colpitts oscillator and a mate that doesn't oscillate]

 At right is the same circuit with reduced breadboard capacitance (1pf). It doesn't oscillate. V(N002) is the base of the left-most circuit. V(N003) is base of the right-most transistor.
[image: transient LTspice simulation, Colpitts oscillator]
I have not used a 5V supply - instead, transistor biasing is done with a large-value 270k base resistor from the +15V DC supply. And I have started base voltage at t=0 with zero base voltage.
In this case, oscillation is above 100 MHz.

Note that probing with an oscilloscope can kill oscillations, especially with a 1X probe. Use a 10X attenuator probe - and it *still* may kill oscillations due to its finite (but small) input capacitance.

---

This emitter follower shouldn't oscillate, but often does because of inevitable wiring inductance and breadboard capacitances.
If you really want to see oscillations, try these changes:

- add a short-leaded capacitor from collector to GND net.
- wire a single-point GND net. You might use a breadboard's long GND strip down one side, but a single breadboard row-of-5 might be better.

If you must use a 1X 'scope probe, then probe transistor emitter. You may not see oscillations there, but you might see the emitter voltage exponentially drop to a slightly lower voltage. This is a clue that adding the probe changed the bias point, or killed oscillations...
In the transient response above, notice how V(N002) worked its way up toward 15V during oscillation, while the non-oscillating V(N003) stayed at a much lower voltage near +5V.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy 270k is a simpler way to bias transistor base, as opposed to OP's 5V DC supply. For this kind of Colpitts, you want the base at fairly high impedance, collector at low impedance.